# Google Maps + Streetview issue - How to disable Photo Sphere

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So on my site I'm using Google Maps + Streetview:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple

Also I'm using standard searchbox with autocomplete, the problem is when I enter some locations, there is no streetview, just Photo Sphere image without any controls for moving around like in standard streetview...

I really don't want Photo Sphere, because I want my users to freely move around with street view, and now they sometimes get "trapped" in one Photo Sphere image... Is there a way I can force streetview without Photo Sphere?

Comment: The panorama is not in the same place as the the center of the map.  Where is the location of the panorama?

Comment: I see your site is updated.  It works now, right?  No more problems?

Comment: Unfortunatly I did not find a solution, just some sort of modification that is acceptable for now. Wen user chooses an address from autocomplete, I don't show streetview from the city couse in a lot of cases this activates Photo Sphere, the location is the same +/- some small amount and then in most cases streetview is shown and not Photo Sphere. For me its redicolous that Google dosent have option to simply switch it off...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to turn off PhotoSpheres, but I did find a workaround that may be useful to you.  I noticed at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewSource that when searching for a location, if you set the source to OUTDOOR, then PhotoSpheres are not returned.

Therefore, if you add listeners for location changes, and then search for the location without PhotoSpheres, I think you should be able to prevent them from showing up.

Here is a modified google maps example to illustrate:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Place Autocomplete without PhotoSpheres</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  #map, #pano {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   float:left;
  }
  .controls {
   margin-top: 10px;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 32px;
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  #pac-input {
   background-color: #fff;
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 300;
   margin-left: 12px;
   padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   width: 300px;
  }

  #pac-input:focus {
   border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  .pac-container {
   font-family: Roboto;
  }

  #type-selector {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #4d90fe;
   padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }

  #type-selector label {
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: 300;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
       placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
<script>

 var map;
 var panorama;
 var streetViewService;
 var DEFAULT_PROXIMITY = 50;
 var MAX_PROXIMITY = 10000;

 function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
   zoom: 13
  });
  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
   document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  //autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
   document.getElementById('pano'), {
    position:  {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    pov: {
     heading: 34,
     pitch: 10
    }
   });
  map.setStreetView(panorama);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
   var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   if (!place.geometry) {
    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
   }
   // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
   if (place.geometry.location) {
    findClosestStreetView(place.geometry.location, DEFAULT_PROXIMITY);
   }
  });

  function findClosestStreetView(point, proximity) {
   streetViewService.getPanorama({location: point, radius: proximity, source: google.maps.StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR}, function processSVData(data, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
     map.panTo(data.location.latLng);
     panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    } else {
     if (proximity < MAX_PROXIMITY) {
      findClosestStreetView(point, proximity + 50);
     } else {
      // NO PANARAMA FOUND - do something else here...
      panorama.setVisible(false);
     }
    }
   });
  }

 }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```